# How to send email programmatically and display success message in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I am new to this magento. I want to send a email and display a success message in magento2. Anyone please give me a solution for sending a mail programmatically.

Comment: You want so send mail from a custom form in front end or in backend?

Answer (score 4):

**Create your controller**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        return parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        try{
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $senderEmail = "sender_address@example.com";
            $senderName = "Sender Name";
            $recipientEmail = "receivers_address@example.com";

            $identifier = 1;  // Enter your email template identifier here

            $requestData = array();

            if($post['fname']){
                $requestData['fname'] = $post['fname'];
            }
            if($post['address']){
                $requestData['address'] = $post['address'];
            }
            if($post['city']){
                $requestData['city'] = $post['city'];
            }
            if($post['state']){
                $requestData['state'] = $post['state'];
            }
            // You can add more data as given above

            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($requestData);

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($identifier)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom(['name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail])
                ->addTo([$recipientEmail])
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Email has been sent successfully.'));
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong. Please try again later.'));
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

    }
}
```

**Add below variables in your email template.**

```
{{depend data.fname}}
{{trans "First Name: %fname" fname=$data.fname}}<br/>
{{/depend}}

{{depend data.address}}
{{trans "Address: %address" address=$data.address}}<br/>
{{/depend}}

{{depend data.city}}
{{trans "City: %city" city=$data.city}}<br/>
{{/depend}}

{{depend data.state}}
{{trans "State: %state" state=$data.state}}<br/>
{{/depend}}
```

> Note: Put the action of your form to above controller.

Answer (score 3):

simple sending email for objManager

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder'); 
        $templateVars = [
                    'message'    => $str_order,
                    'order_no'    => $str_order_no,
                    'order_status'    => $str_order_status,
                    'order_day'    => $str_order_day,
                    'order_email'    => $str_order_email,
                    'order_product'    => $str_order_product,
                    'order_sku'    => $str_order_sku,
                    'order_namep'    => $str_order_namep,
                    'order_qty'    => $str_order_qty,
                    'order_paym'    => $str_order_paym,
                    'order_grand'    => $str_order_grand
                ];

        $data = $transport
            ->setTemplateIdentifier(6)//get temptate id in your create in backend to use variable in backend you should use this tpye format etc . {{var message}} for message  {{var order_no}} for order id
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => 1])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom(['name' => 'automate_order_notification','email' => 'magento_back@pa-phone.com'])
            ->addTo(['email_youwant_tosend@outlook.com','email_youwant_tosend@outlook.com'])
            ->getTransport();
        $data->sendMessage();
```

Comment: It worked for me, but instead of "setTemplateVars($templateVars)" i had to use "setTemplateVars(['data' => $templateVars])". It worked just in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have shared a link for step by step guide to sending a custom mail from Magento 2 using a module.

Magento 2 Uses **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder** class for send custom email.

You need to create a simple module and set **email_tempaltes.xml** file for defining your transaction mail templates.

You can send mail from Adminhtml or Frontend Scope area.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use this Magento 2 SMTP Extension to send email and display a success message. I have tried and really enjoy it.

[Magento 2 SMTP Extension](http://enter%20link%20description%20here)

If you have any problems, feel free to contact with the Customer Support. They are very helpful.